# Update database without opening browser from email link

Tags: java, spring-mvc

An email will be sent to the user, which will have an email link. Upon clicking the link, database must be updated, but browser should not be opened. Is there any way to do this using Java?

Comment: It is for some reason the links are disabled in the clients.

Comment: @Red tiger.  If you can make this work, I don't want to receive any email from you or the organization / client you work for ... ever.

Answer (score 3):

A link would always be handled by the email client, so it's not really up to you to decide if the browser is opened or not. You could, however, add an image in the email that is loaded from a URL which basically could be a script on a server that can do a database update. It wouldn't be triggered by a click though.

Still, it's a bit of a grey area (privacy/hacking etc), and many (perhaps even most) email clients disable loading of images exactly for this reason, so there's no 100% guaranteed solution to do this (luckily!)